# How do I get a variable to be created in Python if not created already?

Tags: python

I've made a rather simple text editor console application in Python, but I'm having a problem at the start. It's rather simple code:

```
if txtrue == 0 :
      txtrue = Empty

if txtrue == "Present" :
    svd = "one"
else :
    svd = "no"
```

I'm trying to define `txtrue` if `txtrue` doesn't already exist. How do I do this?

`txtrue` simply defines if text is present in a different variable.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: If at any place in your program you don't know if a variable exists yet, you're doing strange things.

Comment: Use a `try ... except` statement

Comment: Please include error logs and/or provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the if the name is defined in `globals` and act on that:

```
if not 'name' in globals():
    name = 'foo'
else:
    print(name)
```

similarly, you could peek in `locals` *too* if you're in a function. I'll agree with one of the comments though; this lack of control seems quite weird.

Comment: That cleared half of it, but the variables reset everytime the application is closed. Is that a different question entirely?

Comment: Well if Python finishes with its execution, yes, everything will be cleared. If you need to retain a variable and its value after execution you'd need to save it someplace and look there if it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the variable is `local` or `global`. Python maintains two collections: `locals()` and `globals()` that contains the names of the defined variables:

```
if 'txtrue' not in locals():
    #define txtrue
    txtrue = None
```

for local variables, and of course `globals()` for global ones.

But actually your code looks rather bad designed. You could also give it an initial value like `None` and test whether it still has `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    txtrue
except NameError:
    txtrue = "Present"
```

This should accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if txtrue not in locals():
    txtrue = None
```

except NameError:

```
txtrue = "Present"
```